# Zero experience to A320 in seven months?

Tags: flight-training, fly-by-wire

Some flight schools advertise a "direct path to A320 or B737 f/o after 7 months." Is it a more difficult transition to go to a fly-by-wire aircraft straight out of initial training?  Are there tangible benefits from gaining experience on similar aircraft like the 737, that use conventional steel cables and hydraulically actuated flight controls, before transitioning to fly-by-wire?

Comment: What flight school(s) are you referring to? If the right seat in 7 months is for a U.S. Air Carrier, qualifying in 7 months would not be realistically possible given the number of flight hours necessary to meet minimum qualifications.  Being skilled enough to fly as an F/O in 7 months (starting with no flying experience) is unimaginable. Unless you buy your own B737 or A320 and fly it from the right seat in non-commercial operations I can't imagine a scenario where 0 time to F/O in a B737 or A320 is even remotely feasible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion based. 'Is it a good idea' is subjective.

Comment: To the close voters, please see my recent edit.  It's hard to keep opinion completely out of answers, but sometimes the wording of the question can be geared to encourage a somewhat objective answer.

Comment: @757toga, the question does not mention USA anywhere, and basically everywhere else the requirement for SIC at air carrier is just CPL and that only requires 250 hours (+ type rating, but the hours spent doing the type rating count for CPL too).

Comment: @JanHudec - that's why in my comment I mentioned "If the right seat in 7 months is for a U.S. Air Carrier..." to ensure that it was clear I was referring to U.S. requirements. However, in my opinion, it would be hard to imagine that anyone could go from 0 experience to right seat in an Airbus or B737 especially with 250 hours flight time and within 7 months (and be hired flying for an Airline). That's also why I was interested in what flight school was advertising this.

Comment: @JanHudec, in countries other than the USA is it common to be hired into the right seat of a 737 or Airbus after 7 months and 250 hours?

Answer (score 7):

First, I’m very certain that after 7 months of “initial training” (presuming you start at zero hours) that you would NOT be flying a 737 or Airbus.  You should recognize that sometimes marketing materials are intentionally vague.

Yes, it is very possible that after 7 months of training, (*under the condition that you prove yourself proficient and obtain Private, Commercial, Instrument, CFI and Multi-engine ratings all within that time frame...*) that you may very well enter a "direct path", but there's nothing to say that the direct path won't include a contractual number of years as a CFI at the same school, followed by some other number of years at a regional airline that partners with the school.

Just make sure you understand the specifics of what they are offering, the commitment required, and adjust your expectations accordingly.  If you haven't yet started training you are a LONG ways away from choosing between 737 or Airbus!

However, whenever that transition occurs, the challenges a new pilot faces getting comfortable in new equipment will mostly be related to the physical size, complexity of systems, level of automation, plus company and industry policies and procedures. Whether the flight control surfaces are moving as a result of steel cables or electrons is largely transparent to the pilot while actually flying. Side stick vs yoke may be an issue, but by the time you get there you should have the skills to adapt to either.

Gaining flight experience on larger, increasingly complex aircraft before you upgrade is more important than fly by wire vs conventional.

Comment: +1  Also, you need to get the confidence to be the decision maker without an instructor there as a safety net, that requires a decent amount of time flying solo and a lot of flying in unfamiliar situations.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.
I was recently at a Part 141 flight school in Florida 2 years ago. These  are geared to quicker, airline-like class progression than a Part 61 school.

It took from start of December to early April to get Private pilot license. I had 65 hours (minimum is 40 which is quite low IMHO.) Me and another student finished same day, first in a class of 11. Some students finished a few days later, some a month or two, one barely finished in a year.  Mind you some students had full funding, some didn't, which plays a large factor in speed. We all had some weather delays for long flights, etc.

To get Instrument rating next it took me to mid June. I finished with about 85 hours total flight. Instrument weeds out a lot of non-technically minded or lazy studier students. Some more of my class didn't finish this in 1 year.

Then comes Commercial. The material is mostly a rehash of private pilot. Some students finish single-engine in around 130 hours, and figure a couple months. Most international students do multi-engine commercial training, since foreign airlines often/usually hire with just 250 hours for multi (vs the 1500 in USA, which can be reduced). So from there you would go to an airline academy and learn whatever aircraft they have - which may be anything bigger from DHC8 to B737, etc. US students usually do single-engine commercial, then get flight instructor I and II (where you relearn everything from right seat 30-50 hours or so, learn new material, and have difficult check rides), then much later do multi-engine commercial.

A lot depends when you get Commercial if you can find employment. This is a world of research unto itself for jobs and hour/experience requirements.

Me? I decided to do Part 61 single-engine where you need 250 hours. I rented a plane for 100 hours and flew where I wanted in various weather. I learned a lot more as a pilot than the school would allow in their risk-adverse renting rules. But since doing that, I got off track and haven't finished Commercial since. I would like to get back out there but need money and I have the loans to pay.

Answer (score -2):

It is going to be an opinion base answer if I tell you what I think. Fact is you can go from PPL from scratch to pilot a B737 or A320 within 7 months as only PPL, multi engine endorsement, type rating and multi crew endorsement and something I forget are required. No need even a CPL or ATPL to fly these big planes.

> IMHO you need some experience before flying the big jets. Don’t rush it.

Comment: Technically correct, but realistically impossible for all but multimillionaires.  Just a hunch, but I don’t think the OP is considering buying an Airbus…